# Quorum + Web3js web3.isConnected() returning false

Tags: web3js, quorum

I am running on quorum and using web3.js. When I run `web3.isConnected()`, it is returning "false"

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:22000"));
alert(web3.isConnected());
```

Something I missed out?

Nathan Aw

Comment: how are you running quorum ? one node ? network ? how did you create the network ? what concensus type you are running on ?

Comment: 7nodes example with raft consensus

Comment: i tried that too, it didn't work for me. maybe you need to restart the 7nodes. or check wether the exposed port is the correct one you are using. it could be a problem with web3 too( but that is low probability )